# How does one run a test for a Symfony Console command?

Tags: php, symfony

I find the [Symfony Console documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html) to be quite good. In clear language, it explains how to use Symfony Console to write console commands in PHP, including how to take user input, how to render output, and even [how to write tests for these console commands](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#testing-commands).

However, the documentation doesn't seem to explain how to run these tests. Assuming one has written a test like *CreateUserCommandTest.php*, which they provide as an example, how would they run it?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html

Comment: `php bin/phpunit tests/CreateUserCommandTest.php`